# Var Declarations in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I don't understand `var a = [], i` here. How can `a` be declared as both an array and whatever i's type is?

```
    // Source: Javascript: The Good Parts, p. 63
    Array.dim = function (dimension, initial) {
         var a = [], i;
         for(i = 0; i< dimension; i +=1)
         {
            a[i] = initial;   
         }
        return a;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it means declare both (separately) - not declare them to be equal

same thing as:

```
var a = [];
var i;
```

Comment: Yes 'i' it's also a var. As Trebuchet mentioned, it's like having 2 lines of 'var xx' declarations.

Comment: Yes, `i` is a var.  As this answer states clearly: the above code is the same thing as declaring both variables on separate lines.  The comma separates variable declarations.

Comment: @Kevin it's all about personal preference. I tend to prefer the separate version.

Comment: I personally hate the idea of declaring multiple variables on the same line, but some people like it. In the example you've provided, I think it's a _horrible_ idea to declare both variables on the same line.  If, for some reason, `i` was not declared by that line, it would become a global variable.  In my opinion, the notation in your example makes it much easier to forget to declare `i` (or easier to delete that line and forget that `i` was declared there).  Why not just include the `var` keyword in the for loop??

Comment: I wouldn't normally declare multiple variables on the same _line,_ but I do declare them in the same `var` _statement_ with line-breaks after each comma...

Answer (score 2):

The following code:

```
var a = [], i;
```

is **EXACTLY** the same as this code:

```
var a = [];
var i;
```

It means:

1. `a` is an empty array
2. `i` is an uninitialized var

Answer (score 1):

Javascript variables don't have types.

`a` is *initialized* to an array; `i` is not initialized at all.

Nothing prevents you from later writing

```
a = 42;
i = ["Hi", "there!"];
```

Answer (score 0):

`var a = [], i` literally means ***define a as an array and define i as a variable***. Nothing is actually assigned to i.

For example:

```
var a = 5,
    b = 8,
    c = "string";
```

This basically allows you to define 3 variables without having to use the word var 3 times. Shorthand JavaScript.

Defining your variables before you use them prevent errors if the variable is not present, making functions more reliable. For example, not defining x as a variable will result in:

```
if(x) { /* native code */ }
```

Throwing an error but:

```
if(window.x) { /* native code */ }
```

Will not, because it checks the window object for x, where all global variables are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Javavscript variables does not have any types. Here a is initialized as an array

```
var a = []; //Same as var a= new Array();
```

and i can have any value

```
var i = 0;// Here it is an integer
i = "Hello";// String. Type changed to string. But it is not a good practice
```

Read [JavaScript Variables and DataTypes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_variables.htm)